# IBM Cloud: Connecting two Watson services

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Is it possible that I connect 2 separate Watson services together?

Let's say I wanna use the language translation service with the Watson assistant service, is that thing possible?

Answer (score -1):

Cloud-based solutions often employ a microservices-based architecture. That is, they use several small services together. These services could be built on your own or obtained from service providers like IBM Cloud.

A typical use case is to combine language translation with chatbot technology - on IBM Cloud that would be Language Translator with Watson Assistant. See this recent [blog on multilanguage chatbots](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/the-watson-assistant-guide-to-multilingual-chatbots-186aaf5e99ae) or this older [blog on Watson Assistant and translation](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/build-multilingual-chatbots-with-watson-language-translator-watson-assistant-8c38247e8af1) for examples.